# Play local audio file from android device on HTML5 audio player using Ionic frameWork

Tags: android, ionic-framework, html5-audio

Is there any possibility/alternative to play local audio file (from android device) in HTML5 audio player using Ionic-v3 frameWork ?:

```
<audio autoplay controls>
    <source id="audioSource" src="file:///storage/emulated/0/APP/audio2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  </audio>
```

`App` is a specific folder on android device.

Thank's for your Help.

Comment: Did you ever found a way to do this?